# How to handle os.stat() permission issue? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, stat, eoserror

I'm trying to create a subdirectory if it doesn't already exist. Here is the relevant portion of my function (`TMP` is the constant "-InProg"):

```
def create_directories(parent, tmp_dir=""):
    """
    Terminates program if tmp_dir already exists; otherwise
    creates subdirectories that don't already exist
    """
    if not tmp_dir:
        tmp_dir = parent + TMP
    try:
        if os.path.exists(tmp_dir):
            LOGGER.error('Automation already running')
            return False
        else:
            os.makedirs(tmp_dir)
        <...snip...>
    except OSError:
        LOGGER.error('Directory %s not valid', parent, exc_info=True)
        sys.exit("ERROR: Directory " + parent + " not valid")
```

Here is the relevant portion of the log:

```
ERROR:Directory <parent> not valid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "</path/to/my/script>.py", line 139, in create_directories
    os.makedirs(tmp_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '<parent>-InProg'
```

Clearly `tmp_dir` already exists. But if `tmp_dir` exists then the code shouldn't reach `os.makedirs(tmp_dir)` at all, right? Yet that is definitely the specific line throwing the OSError.

The only clue I've been able to find is that the documentation for [os.path.exists()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) says, "On some platforms, this function may return `False` if permission is not granted to execute [os.stat()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) on the requested file, even if the path physically exists." If this is the problem, what can I do about it?

NOTE: This explanation seems a bit unlikely, because the program itself is what creates `tmp_dir`, and I can't imagine it being able to create a subdirectory that it doesn't have permission to `stat()`. I can't think of an alternate explanation, though. Am I missing some other incredibly obvious bug?